# Confusion With Bitness of Application and Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, nuget, 32-bit, installshield-le

I have a Windows Forms Application written in C#.  It depends on the NHibernate NuGet package, and I am also writing an InstallShield installer package for this app.  All is being done in Visual Studio Community 2015.

Here is my confusion: If I build the application for x64, dumpbin tells me that the app's exe is 64-bit, but NHibernate's DLL and the installer's setup.exe file are still 32-bit.  How can a 32-bit installer wrap up my 64-bit app?  And why doesn't NHibernate become 64-bit when I build for x64, as I thought NuGet packages were supposed to do?  The ultimate question: will my app still run in 64-bit on x64 machines if the installer is 32-bit?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32-bit installer will not prevent you from installing a 64-bit application; at an oversimplified level, all an Installation does is copy files or registry keys into place.

However Windows Installer makes it difficult or impossible to install resources to 64-bit locations unless you use a 64-bit package to install it, for example by redirecting from the 64-bit program files folder back to the 32-bit program files folder. That said, InstallShield LE should be creating a 64-bit package automatically if you target, for example, `ProgramFiles64Folder` or a 64-bit registry key.

Note that the bitness of a setup.exe and the bitness of the .msi package contained within do not have to match.

Comment: Ooh, I think that's the part I was missing.  So a 32-bit setup.exe may still contain a 64-bit .mis.  That makes sense.  One thing still confuses me though: So I can now install 32- and 64-bit versions of my app (verified with dumpbin), but they always end up in Program Files on the target machine.  Shouldn't 32-bit programs end up in Program Files (x86)?

Comment: Yes, but it sounds like you have created a 64-bit MSI package for each, installing in both cases to the ProgramFiles64Folder.

Comment: Ok.  So to install the 64-bit app, I target the ProgramFiles64Folder and rebuild the solution for the x64 platform.  To install the 32-bit app, I target the ProgramFilesFolder and rebuild the solution for the x86 platform.